# Can offset be considered as a variable in Assembly?

Tags: assembly

Can we consider an offset to some memory location as a variable?

In the case where an offset is pushed on the stack as a parameter to a function, is it then considered a variable?

Comment: Sure you can do that. Parameters are normally treated as local variables in the called function.

Comment: Assembly language doesn't know the concept of a variable, so your question is a bit meaningless.

Comment: if "variable" is something what can change, then the particular `symbol` definition being available at compile time is not variable, that's constant. But if you will write that constant into some register/memory (like `mov eax,offset_symbol` on x86), then you can modify that value as you wish, i.e. at runtime the value then becomes "variable" (in register `eax` in that example, i.e. `add eax,10` will add value 10 to it).